# Codeigniter connect to remote database through SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, ssh

I have been searching all morning but can't find a solution to this:

I'm looking for a way to establish a secure connection in my Codeigniter APP to a remote machine using SSH. Using Navicat I can SSH tunnel into mysql and perform queries and I want to connect the same way through my app. Is there a way?

I have openssl installed on my Ubuntu 11.10 server

Comment: Usually you set up the `ssh` tunnel on your server independent of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this : [CodeIgniter - Running via the CLI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html).